# Скрипт на удаление пробела в середине ссылки

Tags: javascript, typescript, скрипт

Ситуация: в одном месте появляется ссылка с пробелом в центре и после этого надо очень быстро вставить в браузер без пробела. Как и где это можно сделать? если это просто то можете написать скрипт или что-то типа того

Comment: Если что-то в предыдущих ответах не понятно, можно задавать уточняющие вопосы в комментарии к ответу, а не создавать второй такой же вопрос...

Comment: По вашему вопросу мало что понятно. Опишите, пожалуйста, подробнее. Где появляется "ссылка"? Она появляется как обычная браузерная ссылка (HTML элемент `a`), на которую можно нажать? Или просто адрес страницы появляется как текст, который нужно выделить и скопировать? И куда вы собираетесь её вставлять? В адресную строку, чтобы открыть в браузере? В поле формы, чтобы куда-то отправить?

Answer (score 0):

Удалить все пробелы из любого текста(ссылки) можно так:

```js
let mystring = 'ht tps ky';
mystring = mystring.split(' ').join('');
console.log(mystring);
```

Взять ссылку:

```js
const ssilka = location.href;
console.log(ssilka);
```

А для остального нужно разрабатывать расширение, для этого нужен англицкий в голове и зайти [сюда](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/)